# CSS word-spacing issue in Safari 6.1/7.0 with text-align center

Tags: css, safari, webkit, osx-mavericks, word-spacing

When I align text center in Safari 6.1/7.0 and add word-spacing, it centers the text as if its width did not include the space in the center.

E.g. CSS

```
div {
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
h1 {
    text-align:center;
    word-spacing: 90px;
}
```

E.g. HTML

```
<div>
    <h1>Text Text</h1>
</div>
```

How it displays in all other browsers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFW3H.png

How it displays in Safari 7.0: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMsKW.png

A demo: jsfiddle.net/2rwa3/2/

Are there any workarounds for this without wrapping the individual words with tags?

Comment: its working fine dr 
**width: 272px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;**
i changed to it

Comment: Fiddle for not wrapping the words with tags. http://jsfiddle.net/jhuangweb/yPDZd/2/

Comment: Still has the same issue in Safari 7: http://i.imgur.com/XmFzDK6.png

See how it's not centered in the box?

Comment: As an update, this was confirmed as a bug by Apple and merged into another open bug.  Not sure on the resolution status.

Comment: I'm trying padding instead of word-spacing and it seems to work (I'm working with icons, so might be irrelevant, but throwing it in, in case it helps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an update, this was confirmed as a bug by Apple and merged into another open bug. Not sure on the resolution status at this time.

Comment: Still not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the h1 to inline-block fixes the issue in Safari.

```
h1 {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    word-spacing: 90px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yPDZd/9/

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't.  Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yPDZd/10/

All I did was update the width of the parent div.  The only reason it worked was because the width was coincidentally correct to put the text in the middle.