# Inline, bullet separated list, that works on the iPad

Tags: css

I want to create an inline, centre aligned, list of terms separated by bullets apart from at the ends of the lines. Like this...

[image: inline bulleted list]

I have it working on Firefox, Chrome & MSIE, but on Safari on the MAC (8.0.8) or on the iPad (OS 8.4.1) the list overflows out of the box. See screenshot below...

[image]

Is there a solution (CSS only, no J/S, and I am using a CMS so I cant easily alter the HTML)?

```css
    ul {
        box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        list-style-type: none;
        list-style-image: none;
        padding: 10px;
        outline: 1px solid red;
        width: 260px;
        text-align: justify;
    }

    ul > li {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    ul > li:after {
        content: " ";
        word-spacing: 15px; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center 70%;
        background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAYAAADEUlfTAAAAf0lEQVQI11XJqw0CYQAE4RnyS+RVQUID1IDgEhI8HnEahSQITqNo4BJawF4BWFAoelgMz03G7CfAvqunJFtkRLipG+Bo29UTwhlSopAgEFkUkhVQACS8Z2hKtBK+tx+vBkCfvPSv9AOTHXL5FeGurgVou9kwcamMA1eSQzM/PZ4yXDPZUumU4gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
    }
    
    ul > li div {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="item-list">    
  <ul>          
      <li><div><span><a href="#">apple</a></span></div></li>
      <li><div><span><a href="#">orange</a></span></div></li>
      <li><div><span><a href="#">raspberry</a></span></div></li>
      <li><div><span><a href="#">bramble</a></span></div></li>
      <li><div><span><a href="#">strawberry</a></span></div></li>
      <li><div><span><a href="#">mango</a></span></div></li>
      <li><div><span><a href="#">tayberry</a></span></div></li>
      <li><div><span><a href="#">bananna</a></span></div></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you paste a screenshot from the iPad too, please?

Comment: @Mr lister - Added iPad screenshot

Comment: for some reason safari is not recognizing the `text-align: justify;` rule.  Adding `display:inline` to the `ul > li` rule helps, but even after that I have to add `content: "\00a0";` to the pseudo-element to get it to even show the dots.  This is as far as I can get it.  It doesn't center the dots: http://jsfiddle.net/5drro912/

Comment: Thanks. It might be related to this bug in safari: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673337/css-word-spacing-issue-in-safari-6-1-7-0-with-text-align-center